# What does this notation $(dy/dx)_f$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, multivalued-functions

If we have :
$f=f(x,y)$,

then what does the following mean and how to compute it : $(dy/dx)_f$ ?

Note : This was found in a mathematics textbook destined for physicists. If it is used differently by mathematicians, I'm interested in its use in physics.

Thank you.

Comment: I learned Calculus back in 1975 and have been around math my entire career. I have never seen this.

Answer (score 1):

It means the derivative is evaluated at fixed $f$, thereby regarding $y$ as a function of $x$. This is more commonly seen with partial derivatives. For other notation, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) viz. @ncmathsadist.

Comment: For a fixed $f$?   What does that mean?  Parodying Art Linkletter, "Physicists say the darnedest things."

Comment: @ncmathsadist It means exactly what it says. If you move along the curve $f=0$, $y$ changes with a certain $dy/dx$ ($x$-dependent, of course). If you do the same for $f=1$, in general you get a different $dy/dx$. With partial derivatives, [it's indispensable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations).

Comment: Interesting.  In other words, it's a directional derivative.